# Where does the high value loot in Emercom Medical spawn?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

On interchange there is a locked room called "Emercom Medical" which supposedly has high value loot in it, but I find it very difficult to find another beyond basic meds and low value tech spawns.  Are there any semi-fixed locations to expect high value tech or high value meds (LEDX?).

Comment: Do you mean within this particular room, or the map?

Comment: This particular room.

Answer (score 4):

One point to note is that high tier loot spawns don't mean there is a guarantee for that loot, you could realistically run into [Emercom](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/EMERCOM_medical_unit_key) 50 raids straight and never find a LEDX.

In this room in particular, you can search the shelves, and beds for a lot of general medical supplies and loose loot. Total lootable list (things not siting in the open) includes 2 Medbags, 1 Sport Bag, and 1 Jacket.

Things like the LEDX, Graphics Card, and Defibrillator can spawn in the metal open dishes that are on tables or on top of hospital beds. You just have to search around the room carefully, you can easily miss them.